# how to load external script in angular without global URL and variables

Tags: angular

I need find a secure approach to load external javascript via URL into Angular web app without global url string or variable defined.

From [here](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/javascript/loading-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular/) I found this approach really good without security issue:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";
import { ScriptService } from "./services/script.service";

const SCRIPT_PATH = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js';
declare let gapi: any;

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private scriptService: ScriptService
  ) { }
 
  ngOnInit() {
    const scriptElement = this.scriptService.loadJsScript(this.renderer, SCRIPT_PATH);
    scriptElement.onload = () => {
     console.log('Google API Script loaded');
      console.log(gapi);

      // Load the JavaScript client library.
      // (the init() method has been omitted for brevity)
      gapi.load('client', this.init);
    }
    scriptElement.onerror = () => {
      console.log('Could not load the Google API Script!');
    }
  }
}
```

where the ScriptService is defined as:

```
import { Renderer2, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

export class ScriptService {
 
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  ) { }
 
 /**
  * Append the JS tag to the Document Body.
  * @param renderer The Angular Renderer
  * @param src The path to the script
  * @returns the script element
  */
  public loadJsScript(renderer: Renderer2, src: string): HTMLScriptElement {
    const script = renderer.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = src;
    renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, script);
    return script;
  }
}
```

The shortcoming is that, it uses global string URL and global variables. Is there a way to bypass global definitions here? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly with “ global string URL and global variables”? You mean the SCRIPT_PATH..? So where would you want to get that from instead..??

Comment: I am thinking of using a static variable from a service component to hold it, and to be flexible this string may be read from json for different environments.

Comment: So, can't you just put it in the environment file..?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want global vars, then you need a database. Use something like google firebase to store that data and retrive it from the DB.